# Which components get locked in a Managed Released package?

Tags: managed-package

I'm trying to determine what limitations I'll have with a package after it has been moved to 'Managed Released'.

Every warning I get is super generic and contains similar verbiage to this:

> If you upload a released version, your package components will be
>   locked, preventing you from changing some properties. See the online
>   help for more details on the properties of managed components.

The [Planning the Release of a Managed Package](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=determine_managed_package_state.htm) page isn't much help either.  It states:

> The package or component was created in the current Salesforce
>   organization and is managed. It is also uploaded with the Managed -
>   Released option selected, indicating that it can be published on
>   AppExchange and is publicly available. Note that once you have moved a
>   package to this state, some properties of the components are no longer
>   editable for both the developer and installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole list of components that can be deleted and those are locked are as below

[Packageable components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm#packaging_packageable_components)

There are times when you really to like to delete the components and in such scenarios you can refer below guide for process

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm

In short its not an easy concept to grasp .You need to familiar with below terms

> Subscriber Deletable,Developer Deletable and Protectable

Comment: Thanks!  I can't say it completely clears things up, but at least the documentation is less generic.